# Defining column in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have created two tables.

```
public  class A {

@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Id
String username;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
List<B> Keys = new ArrayList<B>();

}

public class B {

@Column(name = "key", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Id
String id;

}
```

Now when we see the database table for B, I can see username which is mapped to database table of A.

Now I want to access username in B without any joining. If I write the direct sql I can write that without joining.

How can I do this in hibernate?

How can I create a mapping here?

Comment: You forgot to add username to class B, otherwise what does the OneToMany joins to?

Answer (score 1):

to get all results that are related or not related you must use **rigth outer join**

```
Select A.username from A right outer join A.keys k group by A.username
```

but in your model missing @ManyToOne relationship in class B

Answer (score 0):

For a one-to-many relationship to exists you need to have many-to-one relationship to establish the join. One-to-Many mapping is the inverse side of relationship to Many-to-One mapping. This is used when you have Many-to-One and want to create a association from the inverse side.

So as per the classes you have, entity B is the owning side and entity A is the inverse side.

```
@Entity
public class B {
   @Id
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   private B b;
}


@Entity
public class A {
   @Id
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="b")
   private Collection<A> a;
}
```

You can use the @JoinColumn and @Column to override the column names. I have tried to explain the mappings in simple way here [One-To-Many mapping](http://blog.techdynamic.me/jpa-mappings-one-to-many-mapping/)